# osiset / laravel-shopify Error Call to a member function api() on null

Tags: laravel, authentication, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I've installed the plugin and I followed the instructions for installation.

Now, I received the following error when I call the api method:

```
Error
Call to undefined method stdClass::api()
```

My user model:

```
use Osiset\ShopifyApp\Contracts\ShopModel as IShopModel;
use Osiset\ShopifyApp\Traits\ShopModel;

class User extends Authenticatable implements IShopModel
{
    use Notifiable, ShopModel;
...
```

My controller:

```
    public function themeUpdate(ShopvoteShops $shopvoteShop, $request = null)
    {
        $user = DB::table('users')->first();
        $shopvoteShop = ShopvoteShops::where('url', $user->name)->first();
        $shop = Auth::user();

        $response = $user->api()->rest('GET', '/admin/script_tags.json');
```

Basically, the instances User and Auth everytime are empty and I can't call for example `$shop->api()`, because `Error Call to a member function api() on null.`

I will be glad to hear how to fix this issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fetch the user from the database. `osiset/laravel-shopify` does automatically add shop- and api-informations to the laravel-authentification `Auth::user()` after the user has successfully authenticated himself in the shop.

Take a look into the docs: https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify/wiki/Usage

Otherwise, instead

```
$user->api()->rest('GET', '/admin/script_tags.json');
```

try

```
$shop->api()->rest('GET', '/admin/api/2021-04/script_tags.json');
```

`2021-04` stands for the API-Version.

More Informations you will find in the shopify dev-documentaion: https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/scripttag